# Datatable displayed alonside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

[image]I am new to asp.net I was recently trying to learn how to populate gridview. I have populated the gridview but I am facing an issue which is that my datatable which I am binding with my gridview is also shown on the screen. I can't figure it why it is happening. Please help.

This is my .cs file

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            bindgrid();
        }
    }


    private void bindgrid()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("AmountPrice");
        table.Columns.Add("Currency");
        table.Rows.Add("12000", "USD");
        table.Rows.Add("11000", "Rupees");
        table.Rows.Add("12344", "AED");


        Session["gridTable"] = table;
        GridView1.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table1 = (DataTable)Session["gridTable"];

        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((sender as Button).NamingContainer);

        TextBox tbamount= (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtAmount");
        TextBox tbcurrency = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtCurrency");
        Button add = (Button)row.FindControl("add");

        string vamount = tbamount.Text;
        string vcurrency = tbcurrency.Text;

        table1.Rows.Add(vamount, vcurrency);

        GridView1.DataSource = table1.DefaultView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        Session["gridTable"] = table1;
    }
```

and this is my .aspx File

```
[![<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true"      AllowPaging="true" DataKeyNames="AmountPrice">
 <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" >
         <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="editamount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AmountPrice") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="amountText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AmountPrice") %>' ></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Currency">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="editcurrency" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Currency") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="currency" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Currency") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCurrency" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="add" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="add_Click"/>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoGenerateColumns should be set to false for the GridView.